# Mongoose find 2 elements inside array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have this object inside my current User model:

```
bounty:{
 actions:[{
  approved: boolean
  score: number
}]
}
```

And I want to find User document id but also the array id and  approved: false value to edit that element of the array. I'm trying:

```
filter = {_id: paramId $and: 
      [{'bounty.actions._id': paramActionId},
      {'bounty.actions.approved': false}
    ]};
```

with User.findOneAndUpdate(filter, ...
With no luck.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

PD: image to clarify

[image]

Comment: Do you have field _id `bounty.actions._id` in your bounty collection?

Comment: Yes. Every time I push an element to the array it creates a _id field

Comment: Is local an object that bounty is nested in?  Also, what problem are you having.  is the document not being updated, or is it not even finding a matching document?

Comment: What type of data paramId and paramActionId have? is it ObjectId type or string type?

Comment: parameter types are ok. but the command is updating the first approved false it finds, ignoring elem id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with:

```
filter = {
      _id: b.userId, 
      'local.bounty.actions': { $elemMatch: {
        '_id': b.actionId, 
        'approved': false
      }}
    };
```